# Can a new/modified URL be added to a child component?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

The root of my application is `App`. My `App` component uses `react-router` to route to different pages. For now, I just have 1, but more will come. Each of these pages will render parent components, which will have 2 child components. For each parent component, one child (lets call it `Child1`) is a form that takes some input and makes and API call. The other component (lets call it `Child2`) will render this data in tabular form.

My goal: different parents will be rendered on different routes: `/parent1`, `/parent2` etc. I want `Child1` to be rendered on on the `/parent1` and `Child2` to be rendered on `/parent1?name=something`. The query parameters will need to hold the values of the form inputs the user provides so that I can make this a shareable URL. Anyone with those params should be able to directly see the tabular results. How do I do this?

Here's some of my stripped down code:
`App.js`:

```
const App = () => {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <div>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <Link to="/parent1">Parent-1</Link>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <hr/>

            <Switch>
                <Route path="/parent1">
                    <Parent1 />
                </Route>
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
```

`Parent1.js`

```
class Parent1 extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            products: [],
            isSearched: false
        };
    };

    onFiltersSelected = (products) => {
        this.setState({
            products: products,
            isSearched: true
        });
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Header />
                {!this.state.isSearched ?
                    <Child1 onFiltersSelected={this.onFiltersSelected} /> :
                    <Child2 products={this.state.products} />}
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

`Child1.js`

```
onFormSubmit = (e) => {
  // make API call and call onFiltersSelected from Parent1 
};
.......
render() {

        return (
            <div className="container container-fluid">
                    .........
                    .........
                    <div className="row">
                        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">Search Instances</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    };
```

`Child2.js`

```
class Child2 extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
            ....
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your `Parent1`'s `Route` like `<Route path="/parent1" component={Parent1}/>`, React will pass some props like `location`. You could just do `props.location.name` and test it. If it's null, render `Child1`, if not, render `Child2`.
Source: https://learnwithparam.com/blog/how-to-handle-query-params-in-react-router/

Comment: Any non-hook solution? Im not familiar with hooks.

Comment: @ameyaraje It's worth it to learn hooks. The future of react is going to be relying heavily on hooks going forward. They also simplify your code and help maintain a functional approach which is suggested to make sure you're not mutating your state

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @carlossancal. How do I add the parameters from `Child1` to history? As mentioned in the code, `Parent1` just receives the data from the API and `Child1` doesnt have access to history.

Answer (score 1):

you can install the query-string package from npm [link here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/query-string),
to receive the query strings you use the parse method

```
import QueryString from 'query-string'
const qr = queryString.parse(props.location.search)
```

parse method receives **location.search** object, which comes from **props** and contains keys and values ​​passed by query string

then you could make conditions to render a component according to the received values